# AadHttpClient fails when loading SP page with SPFx webpart in MSTeams Desktop Client

Tags: microsoft-teams, spfx

I added a **Personal Tab** in MS Teams which references a **SharePoint Page** with on it an **SPFx webpart** using `AadHttpClient`.

In the MS Teams **Web Client** the page loads as expected, and the `AadHttpClient` calls work.

However, in the **MS Teams Desktop Client** (on windows) the `AadHttpClient` does not work.

Looking in Fiddler, I can see the following happening (only on the dekstop client):

- A call is made to `/sites/MyDevSite/_api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Internal.ClientSideComponent.Token.AcquireOBOToken?resource='9bebc8ed-8a93-4efc-84a3-ae979d301124'&clientId='add82f27-80e9-45e3-9cf5-345e72d24ff7'`
- The call returns an `HTTP 500` with message:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, System.AggregateException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"One or more errors occurred."}}}

I have no idea what I would have to do to fix this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Personal tabs with SharePoint pages are not yet supported. We hope to get to that fairly soon. Does it work with channel tabs?

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT, I receive the same error in a channel tab. Had a call with Luca Bandinelli in the meantime. He's following up on the issue. - hope to get it solved soon...

Comment: @Nsevens, can you please try it once. I think fix is in place.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT indeed. It's been fixed about a week ago. Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: I have a very similar setup. However I get a different error, `{"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}` @Abhijit-MSFT Do you think I should ask a new question?

Comment: @SahanSerasinghe it's probably best. Either here or on github.

Comment: @Nsevens Thanks. I have asked a separate question on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860729/spfx-webpart-in-msteams-desktop-client-throws-an-unauthorizedaccessexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix has been issued by Microsoft.