# SPFx webpart in MSTeams Desktop Client throws an UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, web-parts, microsoft-teams

This question is very similar to a question which has been asked previously on StackOverflow. However, the error I'm getting is different.

[AadHttpClient fails when loading SP page with SPFx webpart in MSTeams Desktop Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073225/aadhttpclient-fails-when-loading-sp-page-with-spfx-webpart-in-msteams-desktop-cl)

I also have a **Sharepoint Online site** in which I have an **SPFx web part** which makes use of **AadHttpClient**.

This webpart works if I navigate to the Sharepoint site from a browser or open MS Teams web client.

A glimpse of my setup:

[image]

Here is a "steps to repro" overview of the issue I am facing.

- Deploy the web part to SharePoint
- View the web part in SharePoint – web part displays and loads OK
- Add a SharePoint Tab in Teams and bind it to the page with the web part
- View the tab in Teams Desktop client – data fails to load in web part (refer below)
- View the tab in Teams Web client – web part displays and loads OK

When I debugged the MS Teams desktop client, I have this call in in the Network requests tab:

`https://{mytenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{mysite}/_api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Internal.ClientSideComponent.Token.AcquireOBOToken?resource={GUID of my AAD app registration}&clientId={GUID of SharePoint Online Client Extensibility AAD app registration}`

With the response:

Error 403:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891,
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access
>   denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access
>   this resource."}}}

One interesting observation was that this web request only happens in Microsoft Teams desktop client.

I am interested in knowing why this only happens in MS Teams desktop client and not on either the MS Teams web client or Sharepoint Online.

**Update: 10/02/2020**

Another observation: We tried the same setup on a different tenant (personal tenant instead of our corporate tenant). We noticed that the same behaviour could be reproduced when MFA is turned-on on the Azure Active Directory.

The request that's failing is:

`https://{personal tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site name}/_api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Internal.ClientSideComponent.Token.AcquireOBOToken?resource={GUID of the AD app registration}&clientId={GUID of the SPO Client Extensibility app registration}`

However, now the error returned is a 500 with the response:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1,
>   System.AggregateException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"One or
>   more errors occurred."}}}

Similar issue found, (but a different error) out on Github: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4915

Comment: Could you please check the this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl; what url you are getting?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Sure thing. I checked on both web and desktop clients. The value I got was:

`https://{TENANT}.sharepoint.com/sites/SA`

Happy to provide more details as needed

Comment: if the url you are getting is same than it is definitely access issue. Could you check you have appropriate permission to access the sharepoint resource? When a webpart is hosted in sharepoint app catalog, there is option to sync with teams in sharepoint app catalog. I assume you have done that.  It might also cause the unauthorized access.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Yes, I do have access to the Sharepoint resource. In fact, I deployed the web part myself. However, I do not see the Sync to Teams button in the Sharepoint app catalog. Is there a specific permission I should I ask from a tenant's global admin? Also, Do you know why the web part works on Teams' web client and not in desktop client?

Comment: Sync with Teams will be available in sharepoint app catalog. If it is not may be you created the SPFx webpart project v1.7. Still few quick check did you added the sharepoint url in validDomain[] list of your manifest file? Here is the link for [creating web part for teams tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab) and [creating the manifest for webpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/creating-team-manifest-manually-for-webpart).

Comment: It is working on Teams web because it is taking the credentials from cache and authenticating it but teams desktop should be logged in with the same user profile to see the tabs in teams or you can implement authentication in tab.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT So this webpart is basically embedded in a Sharepoint Online site. This Site is shown in a Tab in Teams.  Not as a separate Teams app. Do I still need to do Sync with Teams for that? I did not have to configure any manifest file. since it's added on to a SP Site. I can do a screen sharing session if possible

Comment: sorry for the delay in response. Yes please provide the video so we can look into the issue.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT That's okay. What I meant was is there a way to contact you and do a screen sharing via MS Teams? If I share a link to a screen capture video here it would potentially reveal sensitive information. Let me know how we can proceed. Cheers

Comment: Please reach out to microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com alias and share the video...

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Thank you. I have sent the screen recording to the above email address. I have also added more info to my question

Comment: Didn't got any email yet?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Hi Trinetra, I sent you the email on the 5th. The title was "Issue with Microsoft Teams and Sharepoint Webpart Integration" along with the video to `microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com` It didn't bounce back as well. Could have another look and let me know? Cheers

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT I have also added more info to the question

Comment: Hard luck still no email we got, could you please send it to me directly "singh.nitb@gmail.com" i will start the thread. Let me know your email so we can mail you there directly

Comment: I have sent you an email to the abovementioned email address. Let me know once you receive it. My email is sahan.serasinghe@readify.net

Comment: @SahanSerasinghe did find a solution for this? we have a customer with similar MFA setup, facing the same issue. Would be great if you could help :)

Comment: @Nsevens Sorry mate. It's still unresolved 

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue recently for a webpart that was calling graphAPI. On Desktop teams the call never use to happen and it use to get stuck. I was able to fix it by following these steps: -

Step 1. Visit the new API Permission Management Page on the Tenant Admin Site. This creates a client secret behind the scenes.

Step 2. Go to -> https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps

Step 3. Click on `SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal`

Step 4. Click Manifest on the left menu Step 5. Copy the id from the oAuth2Permission array

```
"oauth2Permissions": [
        {
            "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal on behalf of the signed-in user.",
            "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal",
            "id": "2143704b-186b-4210-b555-d03aa61823cf",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "type": "User",
            "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal on your behalf.",
            "userConsentDisplayName": "Access SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal",
            "value": "user_impersonation"
        }
    ],
```

Step 6. Replace “preAuthorizedApplications” entry with the following json. Keep the appId as it is written below.

```
"preAuthorizedApplications": [
    {
        "appId": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
        "permissionIds": [
            "YOUR COPIED ID FROM STEP 5"
        ]
    }
],
```

Step 7. Hit Save.

Let me know if this works for you. I referred the above steps from https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3923#issuecomment-514726341

Comment: Is this the solution to resolve the issue. I have the same setting in the manifest file, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have a solution that:

1. Delete the app SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal and SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal Helper
2. Wait few mins let the AAD create them again.
3. After that request permission from custom app.
4. Go to API access page to grand again the permission will automatically sync to "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal".
5. Test again the app. Also deactivate the Limited-access user permission lockdown mode could be help.
   Now all my app work as expected.

Why?

1. Limited-access user permission lockdown mode could block your permission to request api.
2. Delete App in AAD to get the the token and all the configuration sync again.
3. The way to grand permission from API Access it correct not grant from AAD App.