# SPFx webpart in MSTeams Desktop Client throws an UnauthorizedAccessException on acquiring token for MSGraph access

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, sharepointframework

On one specific customer tenant we get 403 unauthorized exception when we're hosting an SPFx webpart with a Microsoft Graph connection as a Teams channel tab.

Repro steps:

1. Create SPFx (1.10) solution including a web part which uses default Microsft Graph client to do a GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me call, requesting required permissions
2. Add SPFx solution to App Catalog with tenant deployment check active
3. Approve MS Graph permissions in Tenant SharePoint Admin
4. Sync solution to Teams -> OK
5. Add web part to a SharePoint page -> OK
6. Add the web part as tab in a Team Channel
7. View the tab in Teams Web Client -> OK
8. View the tab in Teams Desktop Client -> NOT OK -> MS Graph data fails to load

We already did the following:

- Checked network trace with Fiddler, we see the following **request**:
  `https://{mytenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{mysite}/_api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Internal.ClientSideComponent.Token.AcquireOBOToken?resource=%27https://graph.microsoft.com%27&clientId={GUID of SharePoint Online Client Extensibility AAD app registration}`
  With the following **response**:
  `{"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}`
- Checked the manifest of the 'SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal' for the correct user_impersonation id in the preAuthorizedApplications entry -> OK
- Tried the same in other tenants -> no issues

Some references which didn't help out:

- https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2521#issuecomment-487962439
- [SPFx webpart in MSTeams Desktop Client throws an UnauthorizedAccessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860729/spfx-webpart-in-msteams-desktop-client-throws-an-unauthorizedaccessexception?newreg=45811f14b9a041de88f7bdb7494cc9b1)

Comment: Could you please check your absolute URL for SPFx webpart?, I think that is pointing to local

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT thanks for your reply! Which URL do you mean? The same app package is used on all other (customer) tenants and is working like a charm. We also checked the package for any absolute URL's. 

By the way: In this specific tenant we encounter the same issue when we add a website tab with the URL of the SharePoint page where the webpart lives to the channel, while in SharePoint it is working fine on the same page.

Comment: Which specific tenant you are facing this issue? Did you checked that tenant have access to you sharepoint app?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @RenevdO unfortunately not, the customer still can't use the SPFx solution using the Graph connection

we do get an other error message at the specific tenant:

{"odata.error":{"code":"10001","message":{"lang":"nl-NL","value":"Missing refresh token."},"error.redirectUrl":"<url>"}}

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT it WORKS in the Teams webclient, but not in the desktop client, so it has nothing to do with permissions or something on the app.

In the meantime the error message in Fiddler has changed to 'Missing refresh token', but behaviour is still the same (SPFx app with Graph connection cannot be used)

Also I'm afraid I cannot share the tenant name/id in public...

Comment: @AdvandenBerg- given the sensitive nature of information, could you please raise this on [Microsoft Support channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business-video/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide)?